# How to delete an Item from the JSON file using UniqueId of clicked item in ListView?

Tags: c#, json, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I've a JSON file like this:

```
{
"Groups": [
    {
        "UniqueId": "1",
        "Name": "England",
        "Members": [
            {
                "UniqueId": "Rooney",
                "Name": "Rooney",
                "JerseyNumber": "10",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "Aquero",
                "Name": "Aguero",
                "JerseyNumber": "16",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "Nani",
                "Name": "Nani",
                "JerseyNumber": "7",
                "Position": "Midfielder"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been able to reach down to the `Members` array of JSON by this code:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Data2.json");
string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);    
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray()[0].GetObject()["Members"].GetArray();
```

I have the `UniqueId` of a Member and I want to search that member with UniqueId for its position within the `"Members"` array and then I want to delete that member. Suppose I've `UniqueId`="Nani", I want to search for that member with unique Id Nani and delete it.

I want the final result in JSON file as:

```
{
"Groups": [
    {
        "UniqueId": "1",
        "Name": "England",
        "Members": [
            {
                "UniqueId": "Rooney",
                "Name": "Rooney",
                "JerseyNumber": "10",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "Aquero",
                "Name": "Aguero",
                "JerseyNumber": "16",
                "Position": "Forward"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will  be better for you to create a class which matches your json tree. I am using .net 3.5 so i think i miss dll for json class you are using. But you will get the logic in this code below, comments will help you too

```
    public class Groups // "Groups": [
    {
        public int UniqueId { get; set; } // "UniqueId": "1",
        public String Name { get; set; } //  "Name": "England",
        public List<Member> ListMembers { get; set; } // "Members": [


        public Groups(string json)
        {
            /* use your json object to get different data */

            UniqueId = "Group UniqueId";
            Name = "Group Name";

            // get all member
            foreach (jsonMember in jsonObject.Members)
            {
                Member member = new Member
                {
                    UniqueId = "jsonMember UniqueId",
                    Name = "jsonMember Name",
                    JerseyNumber = "jsonMember JerseyNumber",
                    Position = "jsonMember Position",
                };
                ListMembers.Add(member);
            }
        }

        public class Member // {"UniqueId":"Nani", "Name":"Nani", ... }
        {
            public string UniqueId { get; set; } // "UniqueId": "Aquero",
            public String Name { get; set; } // "Name": "Aguero",
            public int JerseyNumber { get; set; } // "JerseyNumber": "16",
            public string Position { get; set; } // "Position": "Forward"
        }


        public void Delete(string UniqueId) // by example Delete("Nani")
        {
            ListMembers.RemoveAll(m => m.UniqueId == UniqueId);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've the `UniqueId` of that item. I need to search the JSON file using that Id for the Item to get its position. I mean position of group, or position of member if any?

Comment: Question improved, Please note.